# Changes in XAML are only reflected in English

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization, baml

This is a Localization issue.

I have a XAML for a dialog and I changed some grid column width definition which was set to 120 to be Auto - from:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
```

To:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="120"/>
```

When I set my application to Spanish (for example) and then build the DLL I get **MyApp.dll**, while the changes are not reflected in the dialog at runtime. However when I move back to English the changes are reflected.

I proved this to my self by setting the width to 200 and seeing that it was only reflected in English.

After some investigation, I extracted the Spanish **MyApp.Resource.dll** (yes it is a zipped file).
In it I found a file named **.text** and managed to recognize some tags that pointed directly to my original XAML definitions:
E.g. `ColumnDefinitions ¦ÿ $    óÿ120` or `0,4,0,0` which matches the margin I use and other 'proofs'.

From this I understood that the resource dll contains the compiled BAML of the XAML.

My questions:

- Is it possible to avoid entering the BAML into the resource dll? - I
  would expect the dialog layout to be in the resource DLL only when
  the layout is not the same between languages.
- Is it possible to just have the string table of the different language in the resource dll?

My actual problem is that I have no way of generating the **MyApp.Resource.dll** and see that my changes are reflected correctly also in other languages, since it is done by a third party.

Comment: This isn't a localization issue, this is more of a "I didn't clean before rebuilding all of my solution configurations" issue.

Comment: Also, the xaml shouldn't be tied to your localization at all, but that is an architecture issue.     Your localization should really just contain the text and your xaml should be setup to auto size to accommodate the difference in language length, using resource tags and dynamic binding, you shouldn't have to build a different app for each language.

Comment: It's usual to design layout so the one layout copes with the various different lengths of characters necessary for localised translations.  Delivering updates would be quite a challenge if you had a unique app version per language per version.

Comment: @KevinCook 1) There are hundreds of projects in our application, and a full built takes something like 20gb with all related files needed for debug, this is not practical, I am just building the specific project. 2) and even worst the localization DLLs are not even built by our integration team, this is done by a third party. 3) So how do I do that, disconnecting the XAML from the resource dll. Knowing that is the key, then I can decide if this is practical or if I need to check in my changes - In the hope I did the right thing and wait for the schedule build.

Comment: @Andy You are right, the dialogs do not have specific language layout, and from my point of view it is a mistake adding them to resource DLLs, is this BAML added because of some definitions in the XAML, or in the project? I hope there is a clear answer for that.

Comment: You don't need to build xaml which are just resource dictionaries. You can merge them from raw .xaml files off disk.

Comment: @Andy The xaml is part of some project which I build after doing some layout changes.  How do I avoid the resource DLL in Spanish having this information - which takes over my changes when the application is set to Spanish. The issue is that we have a bug in French and Spanish because of wrong layout, but I can't check my fix and see that the problem is resolved, because the Dialog in Spanish does not reflect my changes only when moving back to English the dialog actually reflects my changes. Note that I am not a localization expert, I am not aware of any tool that merges into a Resource DLL.

Comment: Separate your language specific strings into a resource dictionary and  xaml file per language. Only strings go in these files, not layout. Put these in a separate project. Separate dll. Or uncompiled "flat" xaml files. Then you have no layout in the same dll as your spanish or english strings. You just have strings.

Comment: @Andy This is probably the right answer, unfortunately the specific DLL has many, many string tables (not only one resource file), and taking them out from the DLL is not feasible. FYI - 19 Years ago, give or take, we had two separated DLLs one for the logic and one for the resources for each project, but because we had hundreds of DLLs and there were some performance issue with loading that many... these DLLs were united to one.